# How to use a struct inside a View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct

I have the following struct

```
struct Questions: Codable {
    let questionNumber: Int
    let property, questionID, question: String
    let answers: [Answers]
}
```

Also in my View Controller, I have the following code:

```
var questionList: [Questions] = []
```

In `viewDidLoad()` I have code to retrieve data from the Firebase Realtime Database into `dnaInterview`

```
 questionList.question = (dnaInterview?.questions[0].question)
```

But I get an error:

```
Value of type '[Questions]' has no member 'question'
```

and I really do see the member question in my struct Questions.

Where is my problem?

Comment: `questionList` is an array, so you can't assign a single instance to it, as the error says.  You need to append the value `questionList.append(dnaInterview?.questions[0].question)` - You will need to unwrap `dnaInterview` first though.

Comment: How do I unwrap dnaInterview?

Comment: I think the naming is confusing. Rename `Questions` to `Question` since it is one `Question`. Then you will see you have an array of `[Question]`. So since `questionList` is an array, it has no property named `question`. You need to access the property subscribing it like `questionList[0].question`. Then you cannot assign to a let constant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reference a specific `Question` in order to use the member `question`.

For example:

```
if let question = dnaInterview?.questions[0].question
{
    questionList[0].question = question
}
```

`questionList` is an array of `Question`s.

EDIT: As you say in the comment, `questionList` is empty. You could do the following instead:

```
if let question = dnaInterview?.questions[0]
{
    questionList.append(question)
}
```

Comment: When I do this, first I had to put self in front of questionList. But ... when running the code, when I use po questionList[0].question, I get the error: rror: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
And behind the line of code I get the message: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: That means `questionList` is empty, thus there is nothing at index `0`. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thx Jeroen, with having self. in front of the statement, it works. Nice. I have my data available in my code now :-)